# Screensize optimizasion not working ipad mini iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, ipad

I have tried a lot of different stuff like:
meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
and `@-ms-viewport` and all that to make my site scale correctly on ipad mini and iphone

for some reason I can get the meta tag viewport with a scale of 0.65 to work on the mini, but on the iphone it really big.

hopefully someone here can help me make this work!

[Here is the site](http://loxfear.com/saefe/index.html)

Comment: To be clear - you want the website to scale to 0.65 on load, but only on ipad minis/iphones (or similarly sized devices)?

Comment: Yes, on ipad mini, that looks to be the right scale, but the scaleing only works trough the meta tag, and i have no idea how to make a meta tag that only toggles the mini, and one that only toggles the iphone, since 0,65 is to large for the iphone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it looks like you've mistyped your DOCTYPE declaration, you've put:

`<DOCKTYPE html>`

It should be:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

That aside, if you want the initial scale to change based on screen size you could do something like the following:

```
var screenWidth  = screen.width;
var screenHeight = screen.height;
viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.00');

// ipad/ipad mini/tablet screen sizing
if(screenWidth < 1024) {
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.65');
}
// iphone/smartphone sizing
if(screenWidth < 600) {
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5');
}
```

This would set the inital scale at 0.65 on ipad sized devices, and 0.5 on iphone sized devices.

I would recommend that you look into [responsive design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design) to make the website more usable on tablets/smartphones (it sounds like you're currently just trying to shrink the desktop site, which isn't really a great solution in my opinion)

The above code also only runs on initial page load, if you wanted to run this on browser resize you could utilisie the `resize` event in JavaScript, e.g.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // do stuff here
});
```

You could create a function containing my example code and then run it on page load and page resize.

Comment: my costumer hasnt payed for anything regarding responsive design :) thats why .  ill try what u said and come back

Comment: Ok great, let me know if you have any problems :)

Comment: looks like i had to go down to 0.27 to get the right size! but thx though......   looks like theres a random bug that makes the site on ipad and iphone when this is used, that renders the site blank  weard ;/

Comment: well, it apparently looks good on iphone simulator on my mac, but my friend sais it looks weard on his real iphone